# Animated cartoon series with entire civilization living in the center of the earth

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, animation

Which animated cartoon series is this?

It was from late 80s or early 90s featuring an entire civilization living either beneath the surface of the Earth or right in the center.

The only thing I remember is that the intro and ending songs were catchy, and that the city was surrounding some object that was like the sun, maybe the earth's core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably [***Spartakus and the Sun Beneath the Sea***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spartakus_and_the_Sun_Beneath_the_Sea) (French Les Mondes Engloutis, "The Engulfed Worlds"), also know as Shagma.

Theme song

- [French (Episode 1)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrfSMLuPXLo)
- [English](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGOMnE26jNo)

[image: Shagma]

*Side note:*

---

### Hollow earth theory

---

There are several examples of folk-lore and old religions talking about underworlds. In science the most prominent is perhaps Edmond Halley, (Halley's comet), who in 1692 put forth the hypothesis of a hollow earth. In more modern times the idea is popular among some New Agers and certain conspiracy theorists.

One of the more fun theories are in regards to the secret Nazi expeditions to Antarctica in the years before World War II.

[image: Deutsche Antarktische Expedition]

They claim the Nazis goal for the expedition was to find an entrance to the inner world.

Comment: Cool! the song is even in the iTunes store, and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIgBoZrpgKk) is the guy that sings it performing as a one-man-band

Comment: @rraallvv: Nice, catchy tune :)